# Stored procedure for counting unique books

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'am using `SQL Server 2012` and want to count number of all Book entities that are unique (so if one book has 3 links (same book but with other name/fields) it will count only once).[image: Tables structure]

Let assume, next source:

> **Book**: {Id:1, Description:'Book 1'}; {2, 'B00k 1'}; {3, 'Book1'}; {4, 'Book 2'}; {5, 'B00k 2'}; {6, 'Book 3'}
>
> **Link**: {Id:1,ParentBook:**1**,LinkedBook:**2**}; {2,**2,1**}; {3,**2,3**}; {4,**3,2**}; {5,**4,5**}; {6,**5,4**}

[Script](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c6e2/2/0)

I want see in result: **3** (this is a number of unique books, 2 of which is Id:1 and Id:4 that has links to other books, and 1 whithout links Id:6)

How I can do this by using stored procedure to return just one number?

Comment: What's the part giving you difficulty?  Writing the query or making it a stored procedure?

Comment: whats the foreign key for Book in Link...?

Comment: @DanBracuk, writing the query.

Comment: @HmxaMughal, there are two FKeys:   Link:ParentBook -> Book:Id and Link:LinkedBook -> Book:Id

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your logic a little bit here, instead of linking all the parents books to linked books and then linked books back to parent books, just pick the parent book once and then link them like so:

```
Link: {Id:1,ParentBook:1,LinkedBook:2}; {2,1,3}; {3,1,1}; {4,4,5}; {5,4,4}; {6,6,6}
```

But you have to link it to itself. For the query to find out the distinct.

I created a sample [here on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/34a11/1), check to see if this is what you wanted.
Here is what i did:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(l.ParentBook)) as total_books
FROM BOOK b, LINKED l
WHERE b.Id = l.ParentBook
```

It will count the distinct parent books.

Comment: It give 5 as a result. But there are only 3 different books. To understand problem I posted changes http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c6e2/1/0

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk, no, there are only 3 different books here. If I would like to count rows I can do `select count (*) from Book` without posting question on this site. Books can be listed under different names like: `Book 1` and `B00k 1` or `Book1` (it's one unique book). To make it unique I use `Link` table to link same books. And I want to count unique books.

Comment: @user809808 Oh sorry I didn't get that part :)

Comment: ok let me suggest something here, in the linked table you don't have to link all the books, just select 1 parent book and then set its linked books like so:
`Link: {Id:1,ParentBook:1,LinkedBook:2}; {2,1,3}; {3,1,1}; {4,4,5}; {5,4,5}; {6,6,6}` (the number of the beast...:p).You dont have to link all of them back again

Comment: using the upper comment as logic now see the result in [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/34a11/1)

Comment: @HmxaMughal, now there are 80KLOC of sources for work with DB and more than 1 billion of Links objects into DB, so I can't changed DB in such way. And, btw, your solution is bad for logic, because we need to clear links to same object on model level and find correct books from copies (for example now we simply define links by Link[]->LinkedBook).